# Node js TypeError: Cannot read property 'nick' of undefined

Tags: sql, node.js

### The Issiue

Issue is basically if i  try to combine query+variable or put it in "fake pdo" style, it does not work.

### Code

```
if(page == "profile"){


    var user = "Failed to load.";


    
    con.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '+con.escape(parseInt(userIDRequested)), function (err, result, fields) {

        //console.log(result);
        user= result[0].nick;


        io.emit('userinfo', { nick: user});

    });


}



app.get("/user/:start", function(req, res){
  
    page = "profile";
    var user_id = req.params['start'];
    pageid = user_id;


    if(didshitgetupdated == false){
        useridRequested = pageid;
        didshitgetupdated = true;
    }
    
        
    res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  

    let btlib = btNetLib(res);
    btlib.btSend(navbar);
    btlib.btSendFile("profile/index.html");
    finishConnection(res);
})
```

but for some reason i get this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nick' of undefined
    at Query.<anonymous> (D:\bricktalenode\bricktale.js:36:29)
    at Query.<anonymous> (D:\bricktalenode\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (D:\bricktalenode\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (D:\bricktalenode\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (D:\bricktalenode\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:149:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (D:\bricktalenode\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:133:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\bricktalenode\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (D:\bricktalenode\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (D:\bricktalenode\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (D:\bricktalenode\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
```

### Things i tried

making a if condition to check it
(did not helped)
connecting database using another thing

i used same query(changed variable for php though) in php to access, query is ok, so issue on my node.js code then.

waiting for some time ( did not helped)

parse int

nothing really helped that i done

but for some reason i get stuff correctly using console.log(result);
but i cant fetch them using the code.

### The results

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    nick: '[MODERATED 5]',
    id: 5,
    password: 'fdaf40dc5531c0acf82911892f552f0a',
    banned: 0,
    coins: 0,
    registerdate: 2021-05-10T02:55:45.000Z,
    status: 'BETA STATUS',
    rank: 'Player',
    rep: 1,
    token: 'token',
    lastonline: '2021-05-10 03:05:08',
    lastdaily: 2021-05-19T07:04:34.000Z } ]
```

but i cannot access it

Comment: is `nick` a column? and what is the output of `console.log(result)`?

Comment: yes it is a column

Comment: Looks like `result` is empty, SELECT returned no rows.

Comment: it is full i sent the console.log(result); problem is if i try to read it using `result[0]` data magically disappears

Comment: also data taken using console.log seems to be little garbled especially on the time

Comment: Add error handling, maybe you are receiving an `error` sometimes that is why `results` can be `udefined`.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/user", function(req, res){
  
    page = "profile";
    res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  


    let btlib = btNetLib(res);
    btlib.btSend(navbar);
    btlib.btSendFile("profile/index.html");


    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?';
    

        con.query(sql, req.query.id, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;


        
        
        setInterval(() => {
            var bricklet;
            bricklet = result[0].nick;
            console.log(bricklet);
        io.emit('userinfo', { nick: bricklet});
    },150);
    });


    finishConnection(res);
})
```

moving stuff inside of my app.get solved it.